# 2006 kia Sedona van was driving home and it cut off and had to get it towed home will crank over but wanted start

Tags: kia, fuel-pump, sedona

After getting home I checked the spark and got good spark but was getting no fuel so we pulled the plug wires off the fuel pump and not getting any power what do I need to do

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting power to the fuel pump, the most logical problem would be the fuel pump relay is either not energizing the pump (relay is bad), or the relay is not getting energized (wiring issue or ECU problem).

The fuel pump relay should be located in the engine compartment fuse block. Look inside the cover to see where it is located (it should be mapped). Once found, you can see if another relay is of the same shape/size and swap out the two to see if the pump will run. If it does, good, replace the relay and be on your way.

If there isn't another relay like this one, you can jump the relay slots to provide power directly. Mind you, you have to do this with the ignition switch in the on position. There is usually a small diagram on the back of the relay showing how power flows. Combine the two slots which shows power going into the relay as well as the slot for the wire going out to the fuel pump.

A secondary way to test the relay is by powering it directly (any 12v source can do the job) and listening for the click. You'd also need an extra set of hands to check for continuity across the other pins while the relay is energized. If you get continuity, you know the relay isn't the problem.

If you still aren't getting any action from the fuel pump, supply power directly to the pump (via the wires going into the pump). This is just to ensure you aren't mistaken about power not getting to it in the first place. If it runs when directly powered, you absolutely know the pump is working.

If none of this proves any given part is bad, it has to be a problem with either the ECU not activating the relay or with the wiring between the relay and the ECU. You can check the wiring by doing continuity checks on the wiring. There may be ways of checking the ECU to see it is commanding the fuel pump, but I'm unsure of how you could check that.